# Why is this error showing when I try to use javaws?

Tags: java-web-start, java-6

When I try to use an application with the following command on Ubuntu:

```
javaws http://example.com.br/remote_example.jnlp
```

or simply type

```
javaws
```

The followin error shows up:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libdeploy.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
```

I've searched on Google, but didn't find the answer. I'm sure i'm using 64  bit Ubuntu with 64 bit 1.6 jdk, my coworkers are using the same set up but have no idea what this message is about.

The problem is the java 6 loading screen pops up but after that no signal of the application being opened.

I've installed execstack with apt-get and run `execstack -c` on the library, the message doesn't show up anymore, but the application still won't open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this on the command line solved the problem:

```
update-alternatives --config javaws
```

And then selecting the 1.6 jdk instead of any other appearing there.

For some reason it was using the my java 8 jdk even though my $JAVA_HOME variable was set to jdk 1.6 path.